# Searching for matching records in a field saved as a hash in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, postgresql, hash

I have an active record `SearchSuggestion` that has a `title:text` field for storing values for different languages in a single `hash` that looks like so:

```
#<SearchSuggestion :id 1, link: "/search/shoes", title: {"en"=>"Women's shoes", "ko"=>"여성 신발", "ru"=>"Женская Обувь", "fr"=>"Chaussures De Femme"}>
```

and I'm fetching records that match the given input in the following way: all of the given words contained in all records' `title` fields, starting only from the start of each word the following way:

```
query = params[:q].split(" ").map{|s| s.prepend('(?:.*\m')}.map{|s| s.concat(')')}.join('')
SearchSuggestion.where("title ~* ?", query).limit(10).pluck(:title)
```

The problem is that this gives me matches from the whole field, and I want just the ones for the current selected language. So if I have languages that are using the same alphabet - I get unrelated results e.g - if I start typing "cha" this will return "Women's shoes" by finding the French suggestion as a match. Also if I type "en" - I get all of the existing records as a result, because they match the key for "en" language.

Is there any way I can specify the hash's key that I only want to search within?

Comment: Is the column declared as Hstore or JSON?

Comment: It's declared as a JSON

Comment: Are you sure the column is `jsonb`? I'm not aware of any version of the `~*` operator that accepts `json` or `jsonb` on the left side so I'd expect `SearchSuggestion.where("title ~* ?", query)` to give you an error from the database. If `title` was actually a string and you were using `serialize` then that query would work and that would match your `title:text` note at the top of your question.

Comment: I didn't find anything for using hstore in the project, so I assumed that we're using JSONB instead. `enable_extension "plpgsql"` That's what we have in the schema file.

Comment: `SearchSuggestion.where("title ->>'en' = ?", "foo")` http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb

Comment: You might want to look at the postgres documentation for JSON/JSONB as ActiveRecord does not actually create queries for json/jsonb/hstore/array columns - you have to write them yourself.